# Why SqlDataReader to DataTable only works if I use a separate field?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, datareader

We have a quiet large SQL Server database (about 30 million rows in the biggest tables). When I try to run a stored procedure on it I have a strange problem. It is working if I use this code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("query", conn);    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";    
cmd.Parameters.Add("myParameter", myParameter);    
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

DataTable table = new DataTable();    
var restmp = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
table.Load(restmp);
```

But it is running forever if I use this one:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("query", conn);    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";    
cmd.Parameters.Add("myParameter", myParameter);    
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

DataTable table = new DataTable();    
table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

What can cause this?

Comment: do you call it with EXACTLY the same parameter value(s)?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I tried a lot of different values. (In real I have more than one parameter.) And everytime when I use the first method, it works and everytime when I use the second one, it do not.

Comment: You said *it is running forever* but where does it blocks?

Comment: At the 'table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());' line.

Comment: Yes, on every table.

Comment: FYI you should really encapsulate such code in a [using statement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx). There's a good example [on this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Don't assume SqlDataReader is broken (it isn't). How many rows do you expect in the result? What happens when you run it from SSMS? Use SQL Server Profiler to see what is actually going on. You probably have blocking issues because your code doesn't show a closing statement for the connection, or you are running multiple commands against the same table. Also post the execution plan for your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may be playing **var** roulette. The var declaration determines the type of variable automatically. And when you embed cmd.ExecuteReader() within table.load, you're avoiding that declaration process. Instead, try explicitly casting cmd.ExecuteReader() with SqlDataReader via table.load on your second code snippet.

[Link to C# var reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

*"Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type..."*